# How can I show a systray tooltip longer than 63 chars?

Tags: c#, winforms, systray

How can I show a systray tooltip longer than 63 chars? NotifyIcon.Text has a 63 chars limit, but I've seen that VNC Server has a longer tooltip.

How can I do what VNC Server does?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, it is a bug in the property setter for the Text property.  The P/Invoke declaration for NOTIFYICONDATA inside Windows Forms uses the 128 char limit.  You can hack around it with Reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

    public class Fixes {
      public static void SetNotifyIconText(NotifyIcon ni, string text) {
        if (text.Length >= 128) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Text limited to 127 characters");
        Type t = typeof(NotifyIcon);
        BindingFlags hidden = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        t.GetField("text", hidden).SetValue(ni, text);
        if ((bool)t.GetField("added", hidden).GetValue(ni))
          t.GetMethod("UpdateIcon", hidden).Invoke(ni, new object[] { true });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Any hack for c++?

Comment: No hack necessary, you just need to set the WINVER macro correctly so the compiler knows that you are at least targeting Windows 2000.

Comment: Sorry, I want to get over the similar limitation in `szInfoTitle`, which sets title for a balloon popup. Is there a workaround for that too?

Comment: It is 2022 and this STILL is not fixed. Thanks for the working workaround.

Answer (score 9):

From the MSDN documentation on the Win32 [NOTIFYICONDATA structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352(VS.85).aspx):

> **szTip**
>
> A null-terminated string that specifies the text for a standard
>   ToolTip. It can have a maximum of 64
>   characters, including the terminating
>   null character.
>
> For Windows 2000 (Shell32.dll version 5.0) and later, szTip can have
>   a maximum of 128 characters, including
>   the terminating null character.

It looks like the Windows Forms library supports the lowest common denominator here.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on bk1e's correct answer.

Under the hood, a system tray icon in WinForms is implemented as a Win32 Notify Icon.  Therefore the winforms version has all of the limitations as the native one.  The tooltip size limitation is just one example.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar problem. Rather than hacking the back-end, I implemented a work-around, which makes use of the BalloonTipText, which can accommodate quite a lot of characters.

The tooltip is shown on the first MouseMove event over the tray icon and the tooltip is displayed for 2 seconds. Atter the tooltip is closed, it can be re-opened again by a new MouseMove event.

The only downside with this solution is that is is not possible to close the balloon programatically, when a user, say, leaves the icon area, so it only disappears after a timeout or if the user clicks on the small X-button.

Note that the title and the text can be set at any time elsewhere in the program. They are set here in the event for demonstration purpose only.

*EDIT:* `ShowBalloonTip()` fires addition cascading `MouseMove` events, so it is necessary to disable this event until such time as the balloon tooltip is hidden. Additionally, `BalloonTipClosed` is (according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.balloontipclosed.aspx)) only fired when the user actively clicks on 'X', though I observed it being fired when the tooltip closed after a timeout. I therefore added a helper timer to reset the sate, instead of relying on the `BalloonTipClosed` event. The revised and tested code is below:

```
    private bool balloonTipShown;
    private Timer balloonTimer;
    private void trayIcon_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (balloonTipShown)
        {
            return;
        }
        balloonTipShown = true;
        trayIcon.MouseMove -= trayIcon_MouseMove;
        balloonTimer = new Timer();
        balloonTimer.Tick += balloonTimer_Tick;
        balloonTimer.Interval = 2005;
        balloonTimer.Start();
        trayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
    }

    void balloonTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        balloonTipShown = false;
        balloonTimer.Stop();
        balloonTimer.Dispose();
        trayIcon.MouseMove += trayIcon_MouseMove;
    }
```

EDIT 2: A screenshot of a balloon tooltip with quite a lot of text, that utilises this solution can be [seen in by blog](http://stanislavs.org/bitcoin-miners-in-tray-miner-gui-manager/).

Answer (score -4):

bk1e here says that the limit is 128 chars, now, if you use UTF-16, which is the native unicode format in windows and especially .NET, that means you are limited to 64 *characters*, including the NUL.

I would believe that you're using a unicode API which limits tooltips to 64 16-bit characters (including the null), and that VNC Server uses ascii (or ANSI) api's instead, allowing the use of 128 8-bit characters (including the null).

EDIT: This answer is wrong, here is a helpful comment by Cody Gray explaining why:

> This reasoning is compelling, but is not actually correct. When the MSDN documentation talks about "characters", it actually means the number of char or wchar_t items in the array (depending on whether you're targeting Unicode). So you get the full 128 characters promised when running on Windows 2000+. Windows 9x was limited to 64 characters. – Cody Gray Jun 19 at 4:11"

Comment: Where did you find 32-bit characters? I want some too!

Comment: I don't think they exist, strictly speaking, but UTF-32 uses them as a convenience even though it only needs about 24-bits per character. :)

It's odd, though - I suspect that windows uses UTF-16, so it is curious why they've limited it to 64 characters.  Maybe they're allowing for surrogates?

Comment: I would merely suspect that this is a typical bullshit limit. Someone at MS came up with 64 characters and that's how it is. No rocket science involved, or there simply would not be a limit like this.

Comment: This reasoning is compelling, but is not actually correct. When the MSDN documentation talks about "characters", it actually means the number of `char` or `wchar_t` items in the array (depending on whether you're targeting Unicode). So you get the full 128 characters promised when running on Windows 2000+. Windows 9x was limited to 64 characters.

Comment: @CodyGray: Most helpful comment so far!  Thanks for the enlightenment.