# NotifyIcon not showing complete message

Tags: c#, winforms, background-process, windows, notifyicon

I'm using a NotifyIcon for displaying some information regarding a background process-result of my C# Windows application. But sometimes it does not show the complete message. It hides some of the lines of the given message.

Can any one tell me is there any restriction in this message body? Or how can I force a NotifyIcon to display the complete message?

Comment: If I understand correct then there is a similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579665/how-can-i-show-a-systray-tooltip-longer-than-63-chars

Answer (score 1):

The length of the text of a NotifyIcon is limited to 64 characters. However there's a 'hack' to get around this, please take a look at the solution of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579665/how-can-i-show-a-systray-tooltip-longer-than-63-chars). Hope this helps!